# How does Keras load_data() know what part of the data is the train and test set?

Tags: keras

I'm quite new to Keras and I wanted to begin with a [tutorial](https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python). There, let's say almost at the beginning, the code lines

> Load pre-shuffled MNIST data into train and test sets
>
> (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

emerge. I wonder how Keras knows what of the data is part of the training and what is part of the testing? Though it's quite a basic question I'm not able to see the certain definition in the Keras documentation (the searching even does not provide any result there).
Therefore, I appreciate any help as I often cannot find any command definitions in [Keras](http://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.0/search.html?q=load_data). For other languages, like C++, R, Python and so on it is quite easy to find some definitions. But for Keras, even google doesn't provide me useful searching results (at least not in the first 2 pages).

TL;DR: How does load_data() know what is train and test of the data set?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to find out is looking at Kera's [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/datasets/mnist.py#L11):

```
def load_data(path='mnist.npz'):
    path = get_file(path, origin='https://s3.amazonaws.com/img-datasets/mnist.npz', file_hash='8a61469f7ea1b51cbae51d4f78837e45')
    with np.load(path, allow_pickle=True) as f:
        x_train, y_train = f['x_train'], f['y_train']
        x_test, y_test = f['x_test'], f['y_test']
    return (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)
```

You can see basically is downloading a file which contains the dataset, which is already separated in train and test data. 
The only parameter (`path`) is basically where to store the downloaded dataset.

Comment: thank you! Why is this not officially listed in the documentation? I am a bit surprised by the keras documentation as I hardly see definitions like "function(par1, par2,..)" with explanations for "par1", "par2" and so on. How do people learn keras? :D

Answer (score 1):

For Keras source-stuff, I recommend searching the Github repository - e.g., Google "keras mnist github". From the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/datasets/mnist.py), `mnist.load_data()` *unpacks* a dataset that was specifically *pickled* into a format that allows extracting the data as shown in the source code (also pre-sorted into train vs test, pre-shuffled, etc).

Keras then returns the unpacked data in the form you used above.

Comment: is the dataset you load downloaded on your pc now?

Comment: @wannabecoder Yes, but `.load_data()` doesn't save it by default; can use `np.save(path, data)`

Comment: Does `load_dataset` of any `keras.datasets` always all load data in memory?